# Calling an _id from MongoDB using Flask and Jinja Templating

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, jinja2

I'm very new to flask, python and Mongo - so I am really looking for a walkthrough on this.

I have plenty working on my site, and evidence I can call an _id - but for the love of all good things that Python has brought me, I can't seem to do it again.

I have a section in my made-up social media site for Profile. I want the user to be able to edit their profile and add their name, birthday, location - optional stuff like that.

I can call their blank profile easily and target their username.

But when I go to call the edit_profile and try to target the username I am hit with all sorts of errors.

I tried to go uncomplicated:

```
@app.route("/edit_profile/<users_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_profile(users_id):
    if session["user"]: 
        if request.method == "POST":
            submit = {
                "$set": {
                    "fname": request.form.get("fname"),
                    "lname": request.form.get("lname"),
                    "sex": request.form.get("sex"),
                    "city": request.form.get("city"),
                    "country": request.form.get("country"),
                    "bday": request.form.get("bday")
                }
            }

            mongo.db.users.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(users_id)}, submit)
            flash("Profile Successfully Edited")

        users_id = mongo.db.questions.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(users_id)})
        return render_template("edit_profile.html", profile=profile)
    
    else:
        return render_template("profile.html", profile=profile)
```

But I think someone with the username could then just target this profile and edit it for them. Despite that, this doesn't work either.

I am not really sure where I am going wrong or even where to start to go back to solve the issue. This definitely is not finding the user_id. I am really not sure what else to post here (I can post the Jinja line in the form on the edit_profile.html page:

```
method="POST" action="{{ url_for('edit_profile', users_id=session['users']['id'] }}"
```

Just at a loss here. Appreciate your help (if you can).

Comment: Do you want to edit the profile without passing the user_id in the url? /edit_profile/<users_id>??

Comment: I have just sort of struggled through this... I had lots of issues in the code. 

I am now at the point where I render the form and can insert the data. But it's still a long way off.